# Add Class to another element when class is added to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to check for when a class is added to the body but my code isn't working, is anyone able to help me?

```
function checkFordone() {
    if ($("body").hasClass("done")) {
        $("#mainbar").addclass("finished");
    } else {
        setTimeout(checkFordone, 100);
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D9sUm/19/)

Comment: See also [Watch for Dynamically Added Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068750/watch-for-dynamically-added-class/), [distinguishing html with css sectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499992/distinguishing-html-with-css-sectors)

Comment: Devtools say: "*`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).addclass is not a function`*". It's `addClass`!

Comment: Come to think of it.. this probably should've been closed as a Simple typographical error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

addclass is not a function use addClass!

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? I've checked the fiddle and this is indeed the reason why it's not working. This is clearly a good answer

Comment: You have to check firebug or developer tools. The console would have told you about your typo! ;)

Comment: @icecub Maybe because it should have been a comment instead, and everyone here should have voted to close the question for the typo.

Comment: @Bergi I know, I just commented on the question about that. Was thinking exactly the same